# IOS Apps login via Linkedin authentication SDK

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api

i'm created a **IOS** app in **Xcode7** using swift , and now i am trying to integrate LinkedIn authentication to login into my iOS app.
So i created a account and application in LinkedIn developer site..
But my requirement is to use the same LinkedIn application account to login into my all iOS apps.is it possible?
i heard about deep linking concept.Any one know more about that?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

**Yes it is.** In your app preferences, go to Mobile > iOS preferences, then add the bundle ID of each app you want to be linked with LinkedIn.

> Deep linking : Any one know more about that?

It allows you to **bring users into a more specific part of your app** that is not home page. For example, after opening a notification, you can bring user to a specific post into your app. That is an example of using deep links. Nevertheless, I don't think it is what you are searching for.

Comment: "Yes it is. In your app preferences, go to Mobile > iOS preferences, then add the bundle ID of each app you want to be linked with LinkedIn."                            There is any limitation for adding bundle ID...because i want to add more than 10000 bundle IDs..

Comment: You say that you will publish more than 10000 different apps in App Store ?

Comment: There may be a chance to publish that much of apps into app store in future..so i would i like to know that there is any limitation in that bundle Id adding process..otherwise i need to find another way..

Comment: I just tried for you, I add up to 25 bundle IDs without receiving error message. Sorry, I can't try for 10k :P There's no informations concerning a potential limit on the documentation.

Comment: in Facebook provides a feature link deep link..There is any such like a feature in linkedin

Comment: I think that you misunderstood the deep linking concept. Yes, there is a deep link feature in LinkedIn. But what it allows is opening LinkedIn app to a specific profile for example. **It will not allow you to interact with your app**.

Comment: oh....There is any method to reuse the linkedin application to for all my iOS app ..without adding bundle id each time in linkedin application page

Comment: No there's no such method. LinkedIn apps are not made to be linked with 10k apps. Maybe it's possible but LinkedIn will not help you in this task.